# Azure Terraform Conditional Dynamic Block Asking for Argument When Condition is False

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I am trying to create a subnet module where the delegation block is conditional. My subnet module is set as the following

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnetsforvnet" {
  for_each             = { for subnet in var.subnets : subnet.name => subnet }
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  name                 = each.key
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes

  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled     = each.value.private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled
  private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = each.value.private_link_service_network_policies_enabled
  service_endpoints                             = each.value.service_endpoints

  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = each.value.create_delegation == true? [1] : []
    content {
      name = each.value.delegation_name
      dynamic "service_delegation" {
        for_each = can(has(each.value, "service_delegation_name")) ? [1] : []

        content {
          name    = each.value.service_delegation_name
          actions = each.value.actions
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my module variable.tf looks like this

```
variable "create_delegation" {
  description = "Whether the delegation block should be created for the subnet to be provisioned."
  default     = false
}

variable "delegation_name" {
  description = "A delegation name for the subnets to be provisioned."
}

variable "service_delegation_name" {
  description = "The name of the service delegation for the subnets to be provisioned."
}

variable "actions" {
  description = "A list of Actions which should be delegated. This list is specific to the service to delegate to."
}
```

in my deployment configuration files my main.tf looks like below

```
module "vnet_subnet_extapi" {
  source              = "XXX"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnet.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnet.location
  name                = "vnet-${var.globalenv}-${var.location}-001"
  vnet_address        = var.vnet_address_map.vnet_extapi.vnet_address
  subnets = {
    subnet_apim = {
      name             = "snet-${var.globalenv}-${var.location}-001"
      address_prefixes = ["10.1.1.0/24"]

      private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled     = false
      private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false

      service_endpoints = var.snet_address_map.init.service_endpoints

      create_delegation       = var.create_delegation
      delegation_name         = var.delegation_name
      service_delegation_name = var.service_delegation_name
      actions                 = var.actions
    }
 }
```

and in my deployment variable file it looks like

```
variable "create_delegation" {
  description = "Whether to create the delegation block for subnet to be provisioned"
  default     = false
}

variable "delegation_name" {
  description = "A delegation name for the subnets to be provisioned."
  default     = "delegation"
}

variable "service_delegation_name" {
  description = "The name of the service delegation for the subnets to be provisioned."
  default     = "service-delegations"
}

variable "actions" {
  description = "Whether to create the delegation block for subnet to be provisioned"
  default     = [""]
}
```

When i try to do `terraform validate` I get the error that

The argument "actions" or "delegation_name" or "service_delegation_name" is required, but no definition was found.

Is my variables set incorrectly or is my module not correct?

I thought it was due to my create_delegation variable but even changing it to both true or false I still get the same error. I initially didn't include any default value in deployment variable file cause I thought it wasn't required if my create_delegation was false but I still had the same error. I also tried with default value but that still produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision Azure terraform conditional Dynamic Block asking for Argument when condition is false. I was able to provision requirement successfully.

Based on the code you provided, it seems that the issue lies in the way you are defining the variables in your module and deployment configuration files.

In your module variable.tf file, you have defined the variables delegation_name, service_delegation_name, and actions without specifying a default value. However, in your deployment variable file, you have provided default values for these variables. This mismatch is causing Terraform to throw an error.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the variables are defined consistently in both files. You can either remove the default values from the deployment variable file or provide default values for these variables in your module variable.tf file.

The file structure for the requirement is

```
/root-directory
├── main.tf
├── variables.tf
├── deployment_variables.tfvars
├── provider.tf
└── subnet-directory
    ├── subnet.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

My terraform configuration goes as mentioned.

**root directory**

**main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rgnet" {
  name = "v-sakavya"
}


module "vnet_subnet_extapi" {
  source              = "./subnet" # Update this path accordingly
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnet.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnet.location
  globalenv               = var.globalenv
  snet_address_map        = var.snet_address_map
  create_delegation       = var.create_delegation
  delegation_name         = var.delegation_name
  service_delegation_name = var.service_delegation_name
  actions                 = var.actions
  subnets = {
    subnet_apim = {
      name             = "snet-${var.globalenv}-${var.location}-001w"
      address_prefixes = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled     = false
      private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = false
      service_endpoints = var.snet_address_map.init.service_endpoints
      create_delegation       = var.create_delegation
      delegation_name         = var.delegation_name
      service_delegation_name = var.service_delegation_name
      actions                 = var.actions
    }
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource group."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "Location for the subnet."
  type        = string
}

variable "globalenv" {
  description = "Global environment variable."
  type        = string
}

variable "snet_address_map" {
  description = "Subnet address map."
  type        = map(object({
    service_endpoints = list(string)
  }))
}

variable "create_delegation" {
  description = "Whether to create the delegation block for the subnet to be provisioned."
  type        = bool
}

variable "delegation_name" {
  description = "A delegation name for the subnets to be provisioned."
  type        = string
}

variable "service_delegation_name" {
  description = "The name of the service delegation for the subnets to be provisioned."
  type        = string
}

variable "actions" {
  description = "A list of Actions which should be delegated. This list is specific to the service to delegate to."
  type        = list(string)
}
```

**deployment_variables.tfvars**

```
globalenv               = "dev"
snet_address_map = {
  init = {
    service_endpoints = ["Microsoft.Storage", "Microsoft.Sql"]
  }
}

create_delegation       = false
delegation_name         = "delegation"
service_delegation_name = "service-delegations"
actions                 = []
```

**subnet directory:**

**subnet.tf:**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rgnet" {
  name = "v-sakavya"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name = "demorg-vkvn"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnet.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnet.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnetsforvnet" {
  for_each             = { for subnet in var.subnets : subnet.name => subnet }
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  name                 = each.key
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes

  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled     = each.value.private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled
  private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = each.value.private_link_service_network_policies_enabled
  service_endpoints                             = each.value.service_endpoints

  dynamic "delegation" {
    for_each = each.value.create_delegation == true ? [1] : []
    content {
      name = each.value.delegation_name
      dynamic "service_delegation" {
        for_each = can(has(each.value, "service_delegation_name")) ? [1] : []

        content {
          name    = each.value.service_delegation_name
          actions = each.value.actions
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the resource group."
  type        = string
}

variable "location" {
  description = "Location for the subnet."
  type        = string
}

variable "globalenv" {
  description = "Global environment variable."
  type        = string
}

variable "snet_address_map" {
  description = "Subnet address map."
  type        = map(object({
    service_endpoints = list(string)
  }))
}

variable "create_delegation" {
  description = "Whether to create the delegation block for the subnet to be provisioned."
  type        = bool
}

variable "delegation_name" {
  description = "A delegation name for the subnets to be provisioned."
  type        = string
}

variable "service_delegation_name" {
  description = "The name of the service delegation for the subnets to be provisioned."
  type        = string
}

variable "actions" {
  description = "A list of Actions which should be delegated. This list is specific to the service to delegate to."
  type        = list(string)
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "A map of subnets to be created."
  type        = map(object({
    name                          = string
    address_prefixes              = list(string)
    private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled     = bool
    private_link_service_network_policies_enabled = bool
    service_endpoints             = list(string)
    create_delegation             = bool
    delegation_name               = string
    service_delegation_name       = string
    actions                       = list(string)
  }))
}
```

**Output:**

follow the steps **`terraform apply -var-file .\deployment_variables.tfvars`**

[image]

[image]